# Animate UILabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a custom UITableViewCell with three labels - title, subtitle and right detail.
Now when a User taps on Cell this Cell becomes checked with the normal Checkmark, but I need to animate the right label to the left. I thought I could just do

```
CGRect rect = cell.playerRatingLabel.frame;
rect.origin.x -= 10;
[CLCPlayerViewCell animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    cell.playerRatingLabel.frame = rect;
}];
```

but this appears to do nothing at all. I think it's about constraints but I don't know how to handle this, I'm using auto Layout.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your playerRatingLabel should have a constraint to the right edge of the cell. Your custom cell need to make an IBOutlet to that constraint. Then on the cell tap, animate the constant parameter of that constraint (I've called the outlet rightCon in the example):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    cell.rightCon.constant = 30; // change this value to meet your needs
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Here is the complete implementation that I use to do this. My custom cell had two labels, and I animate the right one when you click a cell and add a checkmark. I created a property selectedPaths (a mutable array) to keep track of the cells that are checked. If you click on a cell that's already checked, it un-checks it, and animates the label back to its original position.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.leftLabel.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = ([self.selectedPaths containsObject:indexPath])? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.rightCon.constant = ([self.selectedPaths containsObject:indexPath])? 40 : 8;
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    RDCell *cell = (RDCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (! [self.selectedPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.selectedPaths addObject:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
            cell.rightCon.constant = 40;
            [cell layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }else{
        [self.selectedPaths removeObject:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
            cell.rightCon.constant = 8;
            [cell layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed. At last an answer that doesn't require frame manipulation which isn't really robust when dealing with auto layout.

Comment: very nice answer thank, I thought about Constraints but didn't know I'm able to set up an Outlet to an Constraint, now I learned :)

Comment: @user1396236, I've added to my answer to show how I did the implementation including un-checking the cells if you click on them again.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to adjust the cell's frame which won't have any effect. Try adjusting the frame of the cell's `contentView`.

Answer (score 0):

i guess following function will solve your problem 
pass your label as cell.textLabel.layer and den pass the point like

```
CGPointMake(0, self.view.center.y)

-(void)moveLayer:(CALayer*)layer to:(CGPoint)point
{
// Prepare the animation from the current position to the new position
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.fromValue = [layer valueForKey:@"position"];
animation.duration = 0.2;

animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];

// Update the layer's position so that the layer doesn't snap back when the animation completes.
layer.position = point;

// Add the animation, overriding the implicit animation.
[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```